# topic proportions in my corpus?

Tags: lda, gensim, topic-modeling, mallet

Thanks for reading and taking the time to think about and respond to this.

I am using Gensim's wrapper for Mallet ([ldamallet.py](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py)), and it works like a charm.  I need to get the topic proportions for my corpus (over all my documents) and I do not know how to do that.  model.alpha is not it as it is not normalized to 1.  Plus, alpha contains my Dirichlet parameters, and not the topic proportions.  Am I correct?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call mallet from the command line, the switch `--output-doc-topics` gives you the topic composition (as a csv file).